# MVC 4 Lookup UserName Based on UserId

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm using the MVC 4 template with VS 2012.  I have enabled a comments section which stores the logged in user's UserId to a table.  When I display the comments I want to display the user's user name and email from the UserProfiles table.

I've tried the following code:

```
public static string GetUserName(int userId)
{
    using (var db = new UsersContext())
    {
        return db.UserProfiles.Single(x => x.UserId == userId).UserName;
    }
}
```

But I get an exception:

```
The model backing the 'UsersContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is pretty descriptive. Your model does not reflect what your database look like. I recommend you to read this about [code first migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621), basically what migrations mean is that you update your database to match your models, its done with one line of command in VS.

Hope this helps

Also I would recommend you to use `.Find()` or `.First()` instead of `.Single()`

Comment: I fixed it by deleting the table and re-adding it.  Thanks for you help.